# In webbrowser control detect video url on iframe

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, webbrowser-control

in my webbrower control i navigate to a site with video inside. In a Windows phone 8.1 silverlight it is possibile capture the video source (MP4) of an iframe WITH Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

- Enable Scripting in your BrowserControl: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled(v=vs.105).aspx
- Inject your custom JavaScript to alter / read the DOM of the website containing the iframe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402855(v=vs.105).aspx

you find great samples on each step, regarding your needs

Comment: hello I know, unfortunately, to get a video content in iframe not think it's possible

Comment: could you query the url of the iframe and load it's content and parse the video there? you may wanna add a html sample of the html you're facing